# Set negative value to show and treat it as ZERO combined with other formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am stuck here.

1. Column "Z" has a value "currency" after a calculation from "W""X""Y".
2. W is the gross sale, X is the fee of the merchant, Y is a refund if any.
3. Some tomes W and Y values are the same. and calculation is like "100+Merchant fee= "Z-100" in this scenario is showing value in minus.
4. I want this value to be max 0 never go and treat negative value.
   please refer to pictures,

[image: The problem]

One more this I want black rows to treat as black and show nothing. currently,it is showing $0.00
[image: The other problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this syntax in the formula

```
=ArrayFormula({"Net Sale";IF(ISBLANK(W2:W),"", 
                           IF(W2:W-X2:X-Y2:Y<0,0,
                              W2:W-X2:X-Y2:Y))})
```

[image]